# How to perform segue from within a SKScene?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, segue, sprite-kit

I have been trying to perform a segue from within a sprite kit SKScene layer. My application requires the user to touch an image on the scene that would push up a new UIViewController. But every time I try to perform from within the SKScene game layer, it gives me output with has no segue with identifier error. I do have a segue and have specified it with an identifier.

My simple question, how can one perfrom segue with a SKScene game layer running? Please help me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segues belong to view controllers, not SpriteKit scenes. If you want to perform a segue from within a SpriteKit node's event handling code, you'll need to look up the view controller that owns the view presenting the scene. For example, in a `SKScene` subclass' `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method:

```
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"id" sender:nil];
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, I had to use the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053436/segue-in-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller

Comment: @RachelHarvey: Sorry, the code in my answer is just one example of how to get a VC you can segue from. What you actually need is specifically a view controller that owns the scene and has the segue you're looking for — if your `SKScene` is presented in a view controller that's within a tab view controller or navigation controller, the root VC probably isn't the one that has your segue.

Answer (score 4):

Swift version :

```
self.view!.window!.rootViewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("gameOverSegue", sender: self)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!