# How can i move from a SKScene to an UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

i've got a little problem with my `spritkit` game.
I have created a little `Jump N Run` game where a penguin must dodge as icebergs or you can also collect fish. As a penguin you have three lives. Are these lives now in the end because you were already met three times of icebergs, I want that one will be automatically redirected to a new `UIViewController` by then finally can perform new actions. I have everything created with `xib` files and now just do not know how I made ​​the `skscene` back to a `UIViewController` gelange ...

Would be great if someone could help me. :)

Comment: might help this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142632/how-to-perform-segue-from-within-a-skscene-layer-spritekit

Answer (score 1):

The most clean solution is to declare and implement a protocol to let the `UIViewController` know that it should react to a change in `SKScene`.

```
@protocol MySceneDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)closeScene;
@end

@interface MyScene : SKScene
@property(nonatomic, strong) SKShapeNode *ball;
@property (weak) id <MySceneDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

View controller that shows the scene should implement a `closeScene` method and set itself as a delegate of the scene. Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    MyScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Set the delegate
    [scene setDelegate:self];

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Then in the scene you can call the `closeScene` method of the view controller which was set as a delegate:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(closeScene)])
    {
        [_delegate performSelector:@selector(closeScene)];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.