# Segue in SKScene to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, segue

In my GameScene.swift file, I am trying to perform a segue back to my Menu View Controller like so:

```
func returnToMainMenu(){
    var vc: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    vc = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
    vc.performSegueWithIdentifier("menu", sender: vc)
}
```

This method is run when a node is tapped:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if gameOn == false{
            if restartBack.containsPoint(location){
                self.restartGame()
            }
            else if menuBack.containsPoint(location){
                self.returnToMainMenu()
            }
            else if justBegin == true{
                self.restartGame()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `menuBack` is the button back to the menu. Every time I run this code, I am thrown an NSException:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ProxyBlock.Menu: 0x165a3e90>) has no segue with identifier 'menu''
```

I checked my segue's identifier and it was indeed "menu".

Comment: A segue is used to go from one viewController to another, not from one scene to a viewController

Comment: You need to call the segue from the scene's viewController, instead of the root viewController.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are calling the segue on the root viewController. I think that is the problem. You need to call the segue on the scene's viewController instead (where I am assuming you have created the segue, hence it is not being found on the root viewController).

Now the problem is that an SKScene does not have direct access to it's viewController, but just the view in which it is contained. You need to create a pointer to it manually. This can be done by creating a property for the SKScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?
    ...
}
```

Then, in the viewController class, just before `skView.presentScene(scene)`

```
scene.viewController = self
```

Now, you can access the viewController directly. Simply call the segue on this viewController:

```
func returnToMainMenu(){
    viewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("menu", sender: vc)
}
```

Comment: This worked. So is the rootViewController the initial view controller in the storyboard? When I printed the rootViewController variable to the console it was showing up as my Menu VC.

Comment: The root viewController is the one which you define in the app delegate, or with the root segue in the storyboard. Every iOS app requires a root VC. Your menu/root VC carries out a segue to your SKScene VC when you start the game. For going back, a segue on the SKScene VC needs to be called, not one on the root VC.

Comment: Hey guys, I implemented this and it works except after the 4th time where you go from a scene to a viewcontroller, where the game lags incredibly. I think that it's because `scene.viewController = self` isn't being dismissed when you leave the scene's viewcontroller for another one - how would I dismiss it so this wouldn't happen?

Comment: Yes, you're adding cards on your stack every time you segue to the menu, you're not going back. In order to actually remove the view controller, change your last step above simply to: self.viewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 1):

How to segue from Scene to ViewController

**Swift 3** - **Works with SpriteKit / UIKit**

You can use **NSNotification**.

**Example:**

1.) Create a segue in the storyboard and name the identifier "segue"

2.) Create a function in the ViewController you are segueing from.

```
func goToDifferentView() {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

}
```

3.) In the ViewDidLoad() of your ViewController you are segueing from create the observer.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(goToDifferentView), name: "segue" as NSNotification.Name, object: nil)
```

4.) In the ViewController or Scene you are segueing to, add the Post Method wherever you want the segue to be triggered.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "segue" as NSNotification.Name, object: nil)
```