# Using Navigation controller for a start screen ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I've come to the point where I need to make a start screen for my game made with sprite kit. I can not get it to show with any of the code and tutorials I have read and watched.

I want to use a navigation controller/view controller to begin at the start screen and have it linked to my app but I am not sure how to link my game's code to the view controller.

Using a  navigation controller, how would I drag it into my game's code as a @IBAction declaration? Thank you.

Edit with current code:

ViewController.m:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

scene.viewController = self;

[skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

MyScene.h:

```
@interface MyScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27056327/2043580

Comment: Change `SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];` to `MyScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It looks like it is working. Now I just have to create the start screen. Sorry for all of the questions, but I just make the start screen with the navigation controllers and viewcontrollers, right? Again, thank you!

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you are using UIKit for the start screen, then you need a separate viewController with navigation useing NavigationController. If you are using SKScene for the start screen, you can simply use the same viewController.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry, but I'm having a little trouble. Right now in my main.storyboard I have a navigation controller and a view controller that is connected to it. My game's code is attached to the view controller (with your help). When I put a button on the view controller it just shows up over the game, and when pressed it goes to a blank screen. I tried creating a new view controller with the button and setting it as the initial view controller instead of the navigation controller, but that just gave me an error. How can I set the view controller with the button to link to the game? Thank you.

Comment: Your navigation controller should be connected to the root segue. Then your start screen should be connected using the rootViewController segue with the navigationController. At the end, your game viewController should be connected to the start screen using a push segue.

Comment: At second thought, I think you should discard navigationController altogether as it uses a navigation bar. Instead, make your start screen the root and use modal segue to the game viewController.

Comment: After running the app it begins with the screen with the start button but after being pressed it closes and gives me an error. This line of code is highlighted green in my main.m: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));... with the error that says "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT. Thank you so much for helping me with this, I've been trying to get it to work for weeks.

Comment: In my main.storyboard I have a viewController set as the initial View Controller connected with the push segue. After running my app and pressing the button the app stays on the starting page with the button pressed down. Is it possible I am messing up something with the second view controller containing my game code?

Comment: Is the segue being called on the press of the button?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Is there a place I can check to give you a sure answer?

Comment: Well, either the segue is connected to the touchUpInside event of the button in the storyboard or calls a IBAction method in the implementation which calls `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"..."];`

Comment: I actually do not think I have either of those. Could that possibly be my problem? I just read a few things on performSegueWithIdentifier and I think I will try to use that. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing. If you have any problems, post a new question!

Comment: Will do, have a great day and thank you for helping me with my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27056327/2043580), but has been translated to Objective-C.

The problem that you are facing is that an SKScene does not have direct access to it's viewController, but just the view in which it is contained. You need to create a pointer to it manually. This can be done by creating a property for the SKScene:

```
@interface GameScene : SKScene

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Then, in the viewController class, just before `[skView presentScene:scene];`

```
scene.viewController = self;
```

Now, you can access the viewController directly. Simply call the segue on this viewController:

```
-(void)goToHomeScreen {
    [self.viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

You can perform other navigationController operations in a similar way.

Comment: I get an error with the scene.viewController = self;. It says "Property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'SKScene'" Do you know how to fix it? Everything is in the right places.

Comment: Have you declared the property in the SKScene's header file?

Comment: The @property is the keyword for declaring a property. Use the code as-is.

Comment: Yes, my code is what is above. Sorry, my comment was getting messed up when I tried to post the code.

Comment: Please post the code for presentScene from the viewController in your question as an edit.

Comment: Edited, thank you. Please let me know if there is anything else I should add.