# Access buttons,labels and uiimageviews from GameViewController to GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiimageview, label

In my GameViewController I have the buttons labels and everything setup. Under viewDidLoad() I have set the labels and everything to `.hidden = true` and my gameOver stuff is on my GameScene file and I cannot set the buttons labels to `.hidden = true`. The button is called backToMenu and if I type it anywhere in the GameViewController it recognises it but when I try to type `backToMenu.hidden = false` in GameScene it gives me an error. Is there any way I could my them accessible in the GameScene as well?

> GameScene Code:

```
func gameOver() {

        bigBox.hidden = false
        backToMenu.hidden = false
        scoreLabel.hidden = false

        var alrentSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MenuSelect", ofType: "mp3")!)

        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var error: NSError?
        screenTapped = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alrentSound, error: &error)
        screenTapped.prepareToPlay()
        screenTapped.stop()

        square1.removeFromParent()
        wallGen.stopWalls()
        //diamondGen.stopDiamonds()
        movingGround.stop()
        square1.stop()
        //square2.stop()


        // save current points label value
        let pointsLabel = childNodeWithName("pointsLabel") as! PPPointsLabel
        let highscoreLabel = childNodeWithName("highscoreLabel") as! PPPointsLabel


        if highscoreLabel.number < pointsLabel.number {
            highscoreLabel.setTo(pointsLabel.number)

            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setInteger(highscoreLabel.number, forKey: "highscore")
        }

    }
```

> GameVieController Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bigBox: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backToMenu: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!



    @IBAction func backToMenuButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuViewController") as! UIViewController
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        var alrentSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MenuSelect", ofType: "mp3")!)

        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var error: NSError?
        screenTapped = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alrentSound, error: &error)
        screenTapped.prepareToPlay()
        screenTapped.play()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bigBox.hidden = true
        backToMenu.hidden = true
        scoreLabel.hidden = true


        // Configure the view
        let skView = view as! SKView


        // store a ref
       // gameScene.gameDelegate = self

        // Create and configure the scene
        gameScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        gameScene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        // Present the scene
        skView.presentScene(gameScene)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variables are in different classes. One way to do this, would mabye be to declare the variables class variables, like this

```
class var myVariable = // whatever
```

if you want to clean up your code, you could also have static getters, like this

```
static func getMyVariable() -> MyVariableType
{
    return myVariable
}
```

This way the variables will be accessible from everywhere, and to access them you type

```
GameViewController.getMyVariable()
```

or

```
GameViewController.myVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a way to access GameViewController methods in the GameScene.  This can be done by creating a reference to GameViewController.  To do this I would recommend looking at this post: [Segue in SKScene to UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053436/segue-in-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller)