# Swift 3 View controller has no segue with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, function, view, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to get my View controller to perform a segue from my Game Scene class when the node "dies". I have copied and used the following code:

```
var vc: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    vc = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
    vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: vc)
    self.viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: vc)
```

In my Function. I also added the code to make the Game scene act as the current view controller. I then created a segue named segue from the current view controller to the next view controller but there was an error

```
FirstMenuViewController has no segue "segue"
```

Any help would be much appreciated as i have been working on this problem for ages and am on the last resort.

Comment: Either you haven't set the segue identifier correctly, or the source view controller isn't the one you think it is and you have put the segue on the wrong scene in your storyboard

Comment: In terms of the main.storyboard i have don that correctly could my code above refer to the FirstMenuViewController which is the initial one instead of my GameViewController?

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint. What is `self.viewController`?

Comment: I used the following link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053436/segue-in-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller

Comment: Fine, but that doesn't change the fact that you have a problem and you have a tool to help solve that problem. The debugger. Learn to use it. There is no need to guess. You can see exactly what is happening

Comment: I don't understand i thought breakpoints just determine which line the problem is on i have identified that

Comment: Hang on i think i found the problem it says first menu view controller has no member segue but i am sending it to that view controller is that the problem?

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on any line to pause the program execution, examine variables and step line by line. The problem is that the scene you have asked to perform the segue has no segue with that identifier