# UIViewController will not segue to another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have my GameViewController that contains a SCNView. I can segue to my GameViewController but when my player dies I try to segue to my GameOverVC but it does not segue. I know the code is being called because I print something to the console. The segue is setup in the storyboard.

[image]

I segue by calling

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameOver", sender: self)
```

I have done this in multiple apps but I can not figure out why this is not working. This is my first app with SceneKit so I don't know if that changes anything but any help is appreciated!

**Also**

If I try

```
let vc = self.view.window?.rootViewController

vc?.present(GameOverVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then it does present the UIViewController but it does not show anything I have added in that view?

Comment: update your question with your storyboard that you put segue .

Comment: the name of it? or do you mean a picture?

Comment: picture that show segue identifier

Comment: Game View Controller is embedded in Navigation Controller?

Comment: yes it is embedded in Navigation Controller

Comment: are you use like 

 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetails"
        {  
             //segue controller code like pass data : id, 
        }
    }

Comment: I am not passing any data, just trying to segue

Comment: @TimmySorensen have you tried to nslog in viewDidLoad method of GameOverVC?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I had the same problem and asynchronous-call rescue me:
I did something like this:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameOver", sender: self)
    }
```

if you need to segue from an object that is not a ViewController inherited class, you need to pass a ref of the parentViewController to your object and make the call like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {

        parentViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameOver", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: This solved my issue! I am not sure why the regular methods like @Lion posted did not work this time but i wish someone could tell me why it has to be done this way in my case.

Comment: This problem takes me couple of days.I don't know why ordinary segue doesn't work.if you understand why it works like this, let me know...

Answer (score 1):

`segue` works for `UIVIewControllers` not for `SpriteKit scenes`. So, you need to perform segue from `parent viewcontroller`, so you can do something  like,

```
 self.parentViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameOver", sender: self)
```

Or as mentioned by [@ZeMoon in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053436/segue-in-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller), you can make property of your `viewcontroller` in `SKScene` class and you can perform segue over this property something like ,

```
 class GameScene: SKScene {
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    ...
 }
```

Then, in the viewController class, just before `skView.presentScene(scene)` do,

```
  scene.viewController = self
```

Now you can perform segue like,

```
  self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("gameOver", sender: self.viewController)
```

OR

Forget `segue` just instantiate your `GameOverVC` and push it on your navigation controller like,

```
    let nav = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    nav.pushViewController(gameOverVC, animated: true)
```

Or

```
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameOverVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :-

```
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"id" sender:nil];
```

Comment: When i try this my app crashes and prints 'Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x7f8785819000>) has no segue with identifier 'gameOver''

Comment: Can you get scene.viewcontroller object in your scene? if yes then performSegue over that object.

Comment: No I can not get that