# Moving from GameVC to another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift3

I got an app which, when you open it, leads you to the main menu where you can select the difficulty of the game. By pressing any button in the main menu, Game Scene is loaded.

My problem basically is that now I want to get to another View Controller, which have the same class as the main menu, after reaching a condition e.g. getting a score of 10 points or something like that.
How can I do this? I have worked pretty much with the storyboard using drag and drop.

I'm very new to swift programming, it would be nice if you could give me some suggestions on how to make it better.

Edit: I got this code:

```
func addScore(playerWhoWin: SKSpriteNode){

    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    if playerWhoWin == main {
        score[0] += 1
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 22 , dy: 22))
    }
    else if playerWhoWin == enemy {
        score[1] += 1
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -22 , dy: -22))
    }

    topLbl.text = "\(score[1])"
    btmLbl.text = "\(score[0])"
}
```

now in the update function I got:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    switch currentGameType {
    case .easy:
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 1.4))
        break
    case .medium:
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 1.0))
        break
    case .hard:
        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 0.7))
        break
    case .player2:
        break
    }

    if ball.position.y <= main.position.y - 70 {
        addScore(playerWhoWin: enemy)
            moveToWinScreen() // <- This is the function I'm trying to write
    }
    else if ball.position.y >= enemy.position.y + 70 {
        addScore(playerWhoWin: main)
            moveToWinScreen()
    }
}
```

The game itself work like it should, I can enter it, choose a difficulty and leave it with a "menue" button in the gamescene (which I linked with the mainmenue via drag and drop in the storyboard)

Now I need the function called moveToWinScreen that should look like:

```
func moveToWinScreen(){

    if score[0] > 9 {
        //here I want to move to the UIViewController that shows you that you won. This UIViewController got the storyboard ID: mainwinVC , and has the same class as the mainmenue: MenueVC.
    }
    if score[1] > 9 {
    //here I want to move to the UIViewController that shows you that your opponent won. This UIViewController got the storyboard ID: enemywinVC , and has the same class as the mainmenue: MenueVC.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too broad. What have you got so for?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. It's pretty hard to explain myself because this is the very first swift project for me.
I got a MenueVC.swift where the buttons for the difficulty are linked and where is an enum for the difficulty.
In the GameScene.swift I declared how the game works, its a pong game so nothing hard.
Well and then some modeling in the GameScene.sks and in the Main.storyboard
I will do some screenshots in a minute

Comment: What I need is basically something like (in pseudocode now) :
`if score[0] > 10 {goto winningscreen0} if score[1] > 10 {goto  winningscreen1}`
I got 2 different VC, each for the player who wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a custom delegate method for this.

For example : [raywenderlich sprite kit tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners)

In this monster game they have used the delegate method to count the monster collision by making a delegate method which is :

```
func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile: SKSpriteNode, monster: SKSpriteNode) {
    print("Hit")
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()

    monstersDestroyed += 1
    if (monstersDestroyed > 30) {
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: true)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
    }
    print("score:",monstersDestroyed)
}
```

in the above code you can see that if the target is achieved it takes the scene to the new view.
Game over scene is the other view which tells the score and result.

Hope this much will help you. For more information you can browse through the upper link .

Comment: but what if the screen where I want to go is a UIViewcontroller ?

Comment: then just push the view controller :
let control = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! Classname
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(control, animated: true)      in place of gameoverscene

Comment: @IPiiro hope this helps you

Comment: Ok I understand but it tell me that "use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard' "

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

Comment: where should I parse it ?
I wrote the `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)` and the function `moveToWinScreen()` in the GameScrene.swift 
Now it complains that : "Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'navigationcontroller' "

Comment: have you embedded your view controller in navigation controller ??

Comment: Actually I don't know.. I embedded my mainmenue in navigation controller

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: @IPiiro https://stackoverflow.com/a/27056327/8432814 see this answer it will help you actually the reason for your error is that the seague works with view controllers not with sk scene

Comment: @IPiiro hope this helps you :)

Comment: Hm.. now it complains in the GameViewController.swift that : "Value of type "SKScene" has no member 'viewController' "
I'm kinda stuck here I guess...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154523/discussion-between-hakikat-singh-and-ipiiro).

Answer (score 1):

**FOR VIEWCONTROLLER**

1.In your gamescene class

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var viewController: UIViewController?
}
```

2. Then in the GameViewController Class

   **just before skView.presentScene(scene)** add this line of code

   scene.viewController = self

[image]

Now, you can access the viewController directly. Simply call the segue on this viewController:

```
func returnToMainMenu(){
self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("menu", sender: vc)
}
```

I have implemented and tried this code and it works fine for me

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27056327/8432814)