# Issue with segue from gamescene.swift to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, segue

I have been trying to perform a segue back from the gamescene.swift to my home view controller, which is the first view to load when the app is opened. The initial segue from the home view controller works perfectly, but no matter what I try, I can't find a way to transition back to this initial view.

My code looks like this:

```
if homeLbl.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
        self.removeAllActions()
        self.removeAllChildren()
        self.removeFromParent()
        self.gameVC?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
}
```

"Home" is the name of the segue that is supposed to go back to the home view controller. When run, and when the home label is tapped, the scene dismisses, the nodes are removed, but the screen goes gray and no segue is performed. Note that the app does not crash.

How should I do this differently so that the initial view controller is presented?

Comment: what is your goal here? why would you want to segue to the viewController? in Spritekit that essentially would be removing any visible scenes. Are you trying to then load an UIKit view?

Comment: @RonMyschuk My initial view controller is a home screen for my game. It contains a UIPickerView for the user to pick a texture for the background of the game. This is why I want to segue to the view controller. When the player dies in the gamescene or exits it, they should be able to go back to the home screen and change the texture if they choose to.

Comment: in Spritekit we use the GameViewController which is a subclass of UIViewController. is your home screen a GameViewController? or do you segue to a GameViewController from an UIViewController?

Comment: @RonMyschuk my home view controller is a UIViewController

Comment: have you checked out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053436/segue-in-skscene-to-uiviewcontroller?rq=1

Comment: @RonMyschuk thank you very much, with some fiddling, this method worked. One last issue, as brought up by a user who commented in that thread: "Hey guys, I implemented this and it works except after the 4th time where you go from a scene to a viewcontroller, where the game lags incredibly. I think that it's because scene.viewController = self isn't being dismissed when you leave the scene's viewcontroller for another one - how would I dismiss it so this wouldn't happen?"

Comment: there could be many reasons that it's not getting dismissed (well outside the scope of this question) what I would do is make sure that you have deinit setup on all your scenes and ensure that each scene is getting deinit called when exiting it. this is a good place to start to ensure that nothing is being retained from a scene.